# Can't import untyped npm module

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I added `paths` and `baseUrl` to my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./built/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
          "*": [ "./typings/*" ]
        },
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

I'm new to Typescript, I really looked it through but couldn't solve my issue.

I'm trying to:

```
--index.ts
import * as VueGoogleMaps from "vue2-google-maps"
Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
 load: {
   key: GMAPS_KEY,
   libraries: 'places',
 }
}
```

I keep getting the error:
`TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof 'vue2-google-maps'' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PluginObject<any> | PluginFunction<any>'.`

I tried a bunch of stuff with `./typings/index.d.ts`

But I'm missing the fundamentals, I know the `VueGoogleMaps` should have a type of PluginObject, but I don't know the syntax to declare it.

I tried:

```
declare module 'vue2-google-maps' {
  import _Vue from 'vue'
  import { PluginObject, PluginFunction } from "vue/types/plugin"
  export default class GMaps<T> implements PluginObject<T> {
    install(Vue: typeof _Vue, options?: T): void
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I don't really want to add `"noImplicitAny": false,` to my tsconfig.json :( I really wished to solve this "the right way"

Comment: `export default class GMaps` - but you're not importing default, you're importing `*`.

Comment: You are right @estus I changed to 
  `export function install(Vue: typeof _Vue, options?: any): void`
and it works! 
lol I knew I was missing something silly. Thank you very much. I was on it for hours!

Comment: @marcelotokarnia Can you share what your final files looked like?  Also, an example of how you used it?  Hoping to save myself the hours that you spent on this :)